# How do I properly import React production build files to another project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm

I am currently building a React application and a separate web app. I want to directly reference my React app in this other app, so I want to know which files or in which order I should import the files that "npm run build" outputs.

So far, on development I've successfully been able to do it importing bundle.js, 0.chunk.js and main.chunk.js (and adding a div with id=root) but for the production the files and names change.

When I see the files output by "npm run build" I see that I have runtime.js, main.js and chunks.js, should I import all of these? Or to they get called in a sequence by just importing one of them?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why not `import OtherApp from ‘other-app-name’`? This is what the package name and entry points in package.json are for. Look at [main](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#main) and [files](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/configuring-npm/package-json#files), etc., in the package.json documentation.

Comment: @rayhatfield thanks for your response. The reason is that I need certain data that I can't get from the reacts app side because of the flow that we are currently using. For this specific case I also can't use localstorage or session storage so thats why I need to render the react app within the other app. Thank you :)

Comment: But if they’re both React/npm packages you should build the first and import it into the other. Maybe I’m misunderstanding something about what you’re trying to do.